# Serializing linked objects

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates

I try to create an object model for the following problem.
I need a folder object (comparable to directory folders). Each folder can contain additional sub folders and in addition parameter objects (comparable to files). In addition, each parameter needs to know in which folder it resides. This is easy so far. So I implemented the following working solution.

I have a base object, that can either be inherited to a folder or a parameter:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Entry
{
  public Func<string> GetPath;
  public string Path
  {
    get
    {
      if (GetPath == null) return string.Empty;
      return GetPath.Invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

Now I created a FolderEntry, that inherits from Entry and supports adding new sub entries by implementing IList<>.

```
[Serializable()]
class FolderEntry : Entry, IList<Entry>
{
  private readonly List<Entry> _entries;

  public FolderEntry()
  {
    _entries = new List<Entry>();
  }

  public string FolderName { get; set; }

  private void SetPathDelegate(Entry entry)
  {
    if (entry.GetPath != null) throw new ArgumentException("entry already assigned");

    entry.GetPath = () =>
    {
      if (GetPath == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetPath.Invoke())) return FolderName;
      return GetPath.Invoke() + "|" + FolderName;
    };
  }

  public void Add(Entry item)
  {
    SetPathDelegate(item);
    _entries.Add(item);
  }
  [...]
}
```

To support Undo/Redo functionality, I made all classes serializable by adding the Serializable-Attribute.
This serialization is working so far using the following test:

```
var folderA = new FolderEntry();
var folderB = new FolderEntry();

folderA.Add(folderB);

var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

serializer.Serialize(memStream, folderA);
```

Now here’s my problem. There is in addition the need that each parameter knows its index inside the hosting list. I changed my Entry-object to have a property Index and a delegate GetIndex in the same manner as Path and GetPath before:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Entry
{
  public Func<string> GetPath;
  public string Path
  {
    get
    {
      if (GetPath == null) return string.Empty;
      return GetPath.Invoke();
    }
  }

  public Func<int> GetIndex;
  public int Index
  {
    get
    {
      if (GetIndex == null) return -1;
      return GetIndex.Invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the SetPathDelegate of the Folder-object I assigned the new delegate

```
private void SetPathDelegate(Entry entry)
{
  if (entry.GetPath != null) throw new ArgumentException("entry already assigned");
  if (entry.GetIndex != null) throw new ArgumentException("entry already assigned");

  entry.GetPath = () =>
  {
    if (GetPath == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetPath.Invoke())) return FolderName;
    return GetPath.Invoke() + "|" + FolderName;
  };

  entry.GetIndex = () => 
  {
    return _entries.IndexOf(entry); 
  };
}
```

If I try to serialize this, I get an expection that my „FolderEntry+<>c__DisplayClass2“ in Assembly… is not marked as serializable. I can’t see an obvious difference between GetPath and GetIndex. To narrow it down, I replaced content of the created GetIndex delegate in SetPathDelegate from

```
entry.GetIndex = () => 
{
  return _entries.IndexOf(entry); 
};
```

To

```
entry.GetIndex = () => 
{
  return -1; 
};
```

To my astonishment this is serializable again. Why doesn‘t cause my GetPath delegate any problems regarding the serialization but my GetIndex delegate does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the anonymous function that you assign to `GetIndex`. At runtime, a new type is created, which is not marked as serializable.

According to [this post](http://jamesryangray.blogspot.de/2010/09/serializing-anonymous-methods.html), you should set a [`SurrogateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the formatter (with some caveats, read the article in detail):

```
formatter.SurrogateSelector = new UnattributedTypeSurrogateSelector();
```

I'me pasting here the classes from the article, for future reference and in order to make the answer thorough.

```
public class UnattributedTypeSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    private const BindingFlags publicOrNonPublicInstanceFields =
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;

    public void GetObjectData(object obj,
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(publicOrNonPublicInstanceFields))
        {
            var fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
            var fieldValueIsNull = fieldValue != null;
            if (fieldValueIsNull)
            {
                var fieldValueRuntimeType = fieldValue.GetType();
                info.AddValue(field.Name + "RuntimeType",
                    fieldValueRuntimeType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
            }

            info.AddValue(field.Name + "ValueIsNull", fieldValueIsNull);
            info.AddValue(field.Name, fieldValue);
        }
    }

    public object SetObjectData(object obj,
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(publicOrNonPublicInstanceFields))
        {
            var fieldValueIsSerializable = info.GetBoolean(field.Name + "ValueIsNull");
            if (fieldValueIsSerializable)
            {
                var fieldValueRuntimeType = info.GetString(field.Name + "RuntimeType");
                field.SetValue(obj,
                    info.GetValue(field.Name, Type.GetType(fieldValueRuntimeType)));
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}

public class UnattributedTypeSurrogateSelector : ISurrogateSelector
{
    private readonly SurrogateSelector innerSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
    private readonly Type iFormatter = typeof(IFormatter);

    public void ChainSelector(ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        innerSelector.ChainSelector(selector);
    }

    public ISerializationSurrogate GetSurrogate(
        Type type, StreamingContext context, out ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        if (!type.IsSerializable)
        {
            selector = this;
            return new UnattributedTypeSurrogate();
        }
        return innerSelector.GetSurrogate(type, context, out selector);
    }

    public ISurrogateSelector GetNextSelector()
    {
        return innerSelector.GetNextSelector();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand anything (yet) of that voodoo inside, but it works great.